# Swagger working with a Web API versioning constraint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a Web API which configuration adds a versioning constraint like the following:

```
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver
        {
            ConstraintMap =
            {
                ["apiVersion"] = typeof(ApiVersionRouteConstraint)
            }
        };

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
        config.AddApiVersioning();
```

Then in the controller you can use the constraint:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/calendar")]
public class CalendarController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("nextworkingday")]
    public  IHttpActionResult GetNextWorkingDay(DateTime? date)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

That works fine in the API, but swagger will not find any controller. My swagger/docs/v1 would look like this:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"SwaggerTest"},"host":"localhost:24460","schemes":["http"],"paths":{},"definitions":{}}
```

How to configure Swagger to understand the constraint?

Comment: If you can upgrade to asp.net core, there's a great project https://github.com/rh072005/SwashbuckleAspNetVersioningShim which solves this in an elegant way

Comment: It is already responded here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376295/how-to-configure-multipleapiversions-in-swashbuckle-using-aspnet-apiversioning